# About a some basis for linear mapping on a plane

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f: V\rightarrow  V$ be a linear mapping on a real 2-dimensional vector space $V$ with characteristic polynomial 
$p(x)=x^2+bx+c$ and with negative discriminant $\Delta=b^2-4ac<0$.
Let $t_1=\alpha+i\beta$, $t_2=\alpha-i\beta$ be its roots.

Then I know that there exists a basis $e_1, e_2$ in $V$ in which  thematrix of $f$ is of the form

$
\left [ \begin {array}{lr}
\alpha & -\beta\\
\beta & \alpha
\end{array} \right ].
$

Is there a basis in which matrix of $f$ is of the form

$
\left [ \begin {array}{lr}
0 & -c \\
1& -b
\end{array} \right ]?
$

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If for all $x \in V$, $x$ and $f(x)$ are collinear, $f$ would be an homothetic transformation. As this is not the case, it exists $a \in V$ such that $\{a, f(a)\}$ is linearly independent.

What is the matrix of $f$ in the basis $(a,f(a))$?

We have $f(a)= 0.a + 1.f(a)$ and $f(f(a))= f^2(a) = (-c).a +(-b).f(a)$ using the equation of the characteristic polynomial. This is exactly the matrix we were looking for!

**The answer to your question is positive.**